# failed to start HUE on Ambari Hadoop cluster

Tags: linux, hadoop, hue

I'm new to big data, hadoop and linux. We have a small 4 nodes cluster, 1 master and 3 nodes, running on Ambari 2.1 and Hadoop 2.2.6  All machines are running on Ubuntu Server 12.04. All properly configured and all works well. Including DNS, SSH, NTP etc. However, when I've tried to install HUE 3.8.1 on top of that, following this guide: http://gethue.com/hadoop-hue-3-on-hdp-installation-tutorial/  the installation successful, and I'm able to open it in the browser and login. But then it shows me 3 misconfiguration:

1. Filesystem root '/' should be owned by hdfs.
2. Secret key should be configured as a random string. All sessions will be lost on restart ... but I've never seted up any kerberos or other security.
3. The app won't work without a running Livy Spark server.

The folder /home/user/hue and everything in it is owned by the hdfs user and belongs to the hdfs group. When first time loged in into HUE, I've created the ADMIN user. Do I need to add this Admin user to some group, if so, to which one? Also,Spark is installed as a part of Ambari package and up and runing. Do I need to install separately Livy Spark or it is again some configuration ?! So confused now ... 
I've double checked all config files, and it looks everything OK for me, any help where to look at or even direction where to dig. All steps in configuration guide followed and replaced with correct ports, hosts and addresses. Any ideas what is wrong and how to start HUE ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Is a warning that the / path of HDFS is not owned by the default 'hdfs'. If the owner is someone else and it is normal, you can update Hue here https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/desktop/conf.dist/hue.ini#L60
2. You should enter a random string of text for the 'secret_key' here https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/desktop/conf.dist/hue.ini#L21, that way nobody can hack your user passwords
3. This warning can be forgotten if you don't use the Spark App http://gethue.com/spark-notebook-and-livy-rest-job-server-improvements/. It requires the Livy Spark Server to be running

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the 2nd bit 'Security Key' is sorted, however, the first and the third are still there. The Spark is installed as part of Ambari, and we going to use it, so does it mean that I need to install Livy Spark components on top of our architercture aswell ???

Comment: And I've double checked now, the default hdfs superuser is set to hdfs user ... a bit frustarted now, where is the bug or misconfiguration. Without these 2 settings set properly, simply cannot start the HUE ... Any ideas what else I can check?! All looks good and identical to the guide I followed ...

Comment: These are just warnings, Hue will work normally for most of the apps. You could blacklist the Spark App as shown in the blog if you don't want to have to start Livy. About the #1, you need to check the owner of /, and chown it to hdfs

Comment: Thanks Romain, I do understand that it is just a warnings, and most of the apps will work. I'm able to use File Browser, run quieries against tables, use Hive and Pig. But, I did install Spark as part of Ambari and we need it to run, I've installed the Livy Spark, but looks like made some misconfiguration, thats why it shows me some errors (Error 504, etc.) when I try to run test or some simple apps. If you can advice me some good documentation/guide on how to configure (Ambari+Hadoop+Hue+Spark+Spark Streaming) it would be great. Also I've noticed, that HBase not working under the hue.Thanks

Comment: And one more question, '#1, you need to check the owner of /, and chown it to hdfs', as far as I understand it is the Hadoop root folder? I wasn't able to change it, when I run chown command, nothing happened, and the Hadoop root folder still owned by the root user. Any ideas how else I can change it to the HDFS user? I've made changes on HUE.INI default superuser = hdfs, but seems that doesn't help me ..

Comment: Another issue, HBase Thrift was installed as part of Ambari cluster, but most likelly HUE can't see it, as I always get an error when trying to browse HBase from the HUE: HBase Thift 1 Server cannot be contacted. Could not connect to <our_hostname>:<9090> Any ideas how to fix that? Our cluster setup: Ambari 2.1.0, Hadoop 2.2.6, HUE 3.8.1 5 nodes cluster, not a Cloudera or Hortonworks ... All servers up and running without warnings and issues. Problem only with Spark and HBase in HUE. How to configure? I've tried all possible solutions, none of them works .. Thanks

Comment: If you want to keep / owned by root, change default_hdfs_superuser=root in hue.ini. About HBase you need the HBase Thrift Server v1 to be up http://gethue.com/the-web-ui-for-hbase-hbase-browser/

Comment: Thanks Romain. All 3 issues sorted now, however cannot access the HBase yet, and Spark Notebook gives an errors. So the next step is to make them work properly. Livy Spark is up and running, so need to figure out how to tell HUE where to look at it.  Will look at the link, thanks for your coments and advice! Will post the outcomes if someone will face the same issues it might be usefull ... Cheers.

Comment: HBase connection timeout issues sorted. If anyone will face the same issues, it turns out that you need to start HBase Thrift Server v1 manually, even if Ambari shows that it is up and running. Simply run the following: '/usr/bin/hbase thrift start' from the command line and restart Hue. Done.

Comment: Nice! About Livy, this is the property: https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/desktop/conf.dist/hue.ini#L1108 Livy is in beta too so feel free to send feedack on the Hue list